# Count number of Divs filtering on id/class

Tags: jquery

Hiii,
**Q->**
I want to count the number of `div` in a page whose id start with d

```
<div id="d1">D1</div>
<div id="d2">D2</div>
<div id="d3">D3</div>
```

I want to get 3 here

---

**Q->**
I want to count the number of `div` in a page which have the class d

```
<div class="d">D1</div>
<div class="d">D2</div>
```

I want to get 2 here

Comment: Thanks for the question. @Sourav

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For the first one you just need a ["starts with selector"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/)

```
$('div[id^=d]').length
```

And the second is just a standard [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/):

```
$('div.d').length
```

The `$()` function call returns an array of matching elements so once you have it, you just need to look at the `length` property to find out how many matches there are.

Comment: Thanks, I Preferred the Class selector.  "starts with selector" is also working but when you have to count how much div you have which contain this class then the second option is useful. Thanks again.